# How can I store multiple values in MySQL that share the same column?

Tags: php, mysql

If one account has multiple values that represent the same variable, how would I go about storing both variables? The number of values could range from one to several hundred. I would think arrays or lists would do the trick or something similar. I've looked through several forums but most of which are old and seem to offer workarounds.

Example:

```
input1 = 5
input2 = 9
structure -> |int|string|,
structure -> |{5,9}|string|
```

Comment: Best way is to replace your column by a table with a foreign key to the first.

Comment: Just don't... storing multiple values in a database column always causes masses of problems; normalize your database structure to handle this as a 1-many relation

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking what I think you are, but take a look at this just in case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: *"I've looked through several forums but most of which are old..."* ... we're talking data normalisation here, this is [not a new concept](https://computing.derby.ac.uk/c/codds-twelve-rules/).

Comment: The accepted response in that link gave a nice explanation and helped clear up some of my confusion. @Don'tPanic

Comment: @csell It's one of my favorite answers. I like to point it out to people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to normalize these values into another table and use foreign keys. This allows you the most flexibility for future queries that you may need.

If you really want to push through and use the same column, you can use MySQL's [JSON Column Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

Comment: If you're not using the data in a relational way, JSON is not a bad call. If you're storing data in there that *is* relational this is asking for a world of hurt.